# how to convert ZPL commands to image without ZPL Printer hosted

Tags: java, printing, zpl

I have bunch of ZPL strings (^XA ...^XZ) and want to render to image file (say PNG).

Currently we have achieved this by sending commands to hosted ZPL Server.

Is there any open source library that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit http://labelary.com/viewer.html 
There you can transform your code to the image and copy it.